# copying large files in c/c++ under FreeBSD freezes system

Tags: c++, freebsd

this code seems to work under Windows (with unexpected results) and Ubuntu. But when I run it under FreeBSD 9.0 AMD 64 it causes the system to freeze. I get error messages like this:
ahcich0: Timeout on slot 28 port 0
Does anybody know what the problem could be?
Thanks.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const string FILENAME = "testfile";
    const string COPYNAME = "copy";
    const int FILES = 5;
    const int SIZE_MULTIPLIER = 6;
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = pow(2.0, 16);

    time_t times[2][FILES];

    srand (time(NULL));

    // create test files
    for (int i = 1; i < FILES + 1; i++){
        ofstream os;
        string filename(FILENAME);
        filename += (char)i + 48;
        os.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
        if (os.is_open()){
            cout << "Writing file " << i << " of " << FILES;
            long filesize =pow(2.0, i * SIZE_MULTIPLIER);
            cout << " (" << filesize << " bytes)" <<  endl;

            while(filesize--){
                os << (char)(rand() % 256);
            }
            cout << os.tellp() << " bytes written.\n";
            os.close();
        }else{
            cerr << "Could not create file " << filename;
            cerr << endl;
        }
    }

    // copy the files
    timeval tv;
    time_t start;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char ci;
    for (int i = 0; i < FILES; i++){
        ci = (char)i + 49;
        string filename(FILENAME);
        filename += ci;
        string copyname("c");
        copyname += COPYNAME;
        copyname += ci;

        cout << "Copying file " << filename.c_str() << endl;

        cout << "the c way: "; 
        cout.flush();

        start = time(NULL);

        FILE *pFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "rb");
        FILE *pCopy = fopen(copyname.c_str(), "wb");
        if (!(pFile == NULL || pCopy == NULL)){
            do{
                int bytesRead = fread(
                    buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, pFile);

                fwrite(buffer, 1, bytesRead, pCopy);
            }while(!feof(pFile));
            fclose(pFile);
            fclose(pCopy);

            cout << " Done.\n";
        }else{
            cerr << "Could not open either " << filename;
            cerr << " or " << copyname << endl;
        }

        times[0][i] = time(NULL) - start;
        remove(copyname.c_str());

        copyname = "cpp";
        copyname += COPYNAME;
        copyname += ci;

        cout << "the c++ way: ";
        cout.flush();

        start = time(NULL);

        ifstream in;
        in.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);
        in.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
        ofstream out;
        out.open(copyname.c_str(), ios::binary);
        char copyBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
        out.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(copyBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

        if (in.is_open() && out.is_open()){
            out << in.rdbuf();
            in.close();
            out.close();
            cout << " Done.\n";
        }else{
            cerr << "Could not open either " << filename;
            cerr << " or " << copyname << endl;
        }

        times[1][i] = time(NULL) - start ;
        remove(copyname.c_str());
    }

    cout << "Summary:\n";
    cout << "\tc\tc++\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < FILES; i++){
        ci = (char)i + 49;
        cout << "copy" << ci << "\t" << times[0][i];
        cout << "\t" << times[1][i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In short, your hardware is broken (or the OS is not configured correctly to work with it). This is not a programming problem.

Comment: Have you looked into what `dmesg` says? How about `df -h`? Enough disk space?

Comment: Yeah, probably FreeBSD has trouble working with your hardware, if in Windows/Linux it works properly (I assume we're talking about the same machine).

Comment: thanks for your answers. I still hope, the hardware is not broken. What could I ask dmesg? And yes, it's the same machine.
Edit: There's enough disk space left

Comment: What does "with unexpected results" mean in the context of Windows?

Comment: unexpected means, that it takes a lot more time copying the huge file via the streams

Comment: Just a side note: you are using -CURRENT, and first minor version of the -CURRENT to boot. There might be quite a few bugs in this version. Try updating to the latest revision, or, rather, downgrading to -STABLE.

Comment: @Senna: -CURRENT is very different from a full -RELEASE (9.0 was released in January 2012). -STABLE is also not what every Linux distribution would consider "stable". -STABLE is a bunch of changes on top of -RELEASE, the ABI is stable, but the code isn't. -CURRENT is the absolute latest version of the code in svn. -STABLE would be an upgrade from 9.0-RELEASE not a downgrade.

Comment: actually Senna's answer was correct. This can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

After changing FILES to 4 (because it takes very long otherwise), your program ran just fine here:

```
Writing file 1 of 4 (64 bytes)
64 bytes written.
Writing file 2 of 4 (4096 bytes)
4096 bytes written.
Writing file 3 of 4 (262144 bytes)
262144 bytes written.
Writing file 4 of 4 (16777216 bytes)
16777216 bytes written.
Copying file testfile1
the c way:  Done.
the c++ way:  Done.
Copying file testfile2
the c way:  Done.
the c++ way:  Done.
Copying file testfile3
the c way:  Done.
the c++ way:  Done.
Copying file testfile4
the c way:  Done.
the c++ way:  Done.
Summary:
        c       c++
copy1   0       0
copy2   0       0
copy3   0       0
copy4   0       0
```

(FreeBSD 9.0-RELEASE-p3 amd64, compiled with clang++)

Answer (score 1):

There could've been a bug in the achi-driver in 9.0, that showed up under *heavy* load. Or, it could've been a buggy controller, that was failing under the same load -- and not failing under other OSes, because they weren't taxing it as much.

Is this still a problem with FreeBSD 9.2?

As for your program, you ought to check not just for `feof()`, but also for `ferror()` in your read/write loop. Further, in my opinion, such read/write loops are a thing from the past. These days, when `size_t` and `offset_t` are of the same width (64-bit platforms), you ought to simply `mmap()` your source file and `fwrite` it into destination in one go. Look, ma, no loop!